# Is it possible to develop own interface for regular TV with Android or WebOS?

Tags: android, android-tv, webos, smart-tv

Is it possible to develop applications for Android TV or TVs with WebOS that will include analog, satellite or cable broadcasting that the TV has built-in?

To be clear, I want to develop an application for smart TVs that will be using the internal broadcast (analog, satellite or cable).

Comment: Maybe this [TV Input Framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/) could help you...

Comment: You can check the [Build layouts for TV](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts#leanback-theme) as it's the closest to creating a customize interface for Android TV. You can use the [leanback theme](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback), the [NoTitleBar theme](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts#notitle-theme), and the [Build basic TV layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts#structure).

Comment: Thanks @Jesus Pocoata. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks to you too @noogui, that might be what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesús Pocoata said, on AndroidTV you can use the [TIF](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/) to manage TV entries, but unfortunately, I think this is not possible in WebOS

You can also consult the Samsung SmartTV platform, it has some PIP functions for SmartTV applications [Tizen PIP](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/pip-picture-in-picture/managing-pip-windows/)

Comment: Thanks @stuckatzero. I will try and let you know.